# How to rewrite outgoing email address to SMTP login name in postfix?

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, sasl, dovecot

I host a mail server, where users log in via SMTP to send email.
The current config of postfix allows every authenticated user to send emails with any sender address.
My objective is to prevent users sending mail with an other FROM: address than the sender’s own SMTP login name.
For example: if you log in with the username bob, you’re only allowed to send emails with the sender address bob@example.com.

`smtpd_sender_restrictions` could be a solution, but this would reject clients, who entered any other address.

A more elegant way would be to automatically rewrite all from addresses to the username they logged in with. That's, what I'm trying to achieve.

Just like Gmail, if you use it as an SMTP service to send emails, the messages are sent with the address you logged in to Gmail.

Currently the SMTP authentication is done by dovecot:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

The server itself is really simple, no fancy custom per-user based stuff or multi-domain setup, just users SMTPing in, and sending emails. :-)

I know that `smtp_generic_maps` and `sender_canonical_maps` exist, but I coudn't find the way to **automatically** rewrite the senders address.
By automatically I mean not one-by-one in a separate file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe using `sender_canonical_maps` in conjunction with `smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch`?

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch